# Is is possible to launch the Android "Google Sheets" app and show a Google Drive sheet via an intent from a custom app?

Tags: android, google-sheets

I have an Android app that appends data to a Google Drive Spreadsheet doc. This app is good at one thing -- appending a row of data based on a convenient API (for this kind of data). This app just uses the Google Sheets Api

It would be very nice to be add an option to my app to launch the more full featured "Google Sheets" app on this spreadsheet using `startActivity(Intent)`, for example to delete a row added incorrectly. Obviously my app could use the Sheets Api to do things other than just append new rows, but leveraging the existing app would be much easier.

Does the "Google Sheets" Android app handle `Intent`s, and if so where is this documended or how can it be done?

Answer (score 0):

This is very simple. Install the Google Sheets App, and then displaying a sheet in Sheets is just:

`startActivity(Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(fileInfo.webViewLink)))`

`fileInfo` is what you get using the Google API's drive service to get the `com.google.api.services.drive.model.File` for the sheet, making sure to include `webViewLink` in the returned fields.